# How can I enter a shortcode on a 4G iPad?

Tags: ipad, cellular-data

I'm using a prepaid wireless carrier with my iPad.  I can buy codes for the carrier that add credit to my account.  On a cell phone, I'd dial these codes using something like `*101*(digits)#`.  The iPad doesn't appear to have a "dialer" -- is it possible to enter this sort of code *somewhere*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything I've seen seems to indicate that no, there's no way to send a shortcode to your network provider on any iPad.  This is dumb, but apparently par for the course :(